# Sensitivity analysis of QP

Tags: quadratic-programming, sensitivity-analysis

Given a quadratic program
$$
f^* \equiv x^\top Q x + b^\top x \\
x \geq 0 \\
A^\top x = d \\
x \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
I would like to analyze the sensitivity of the solution $x^*$ to perturbations in $Q$ and $b$.
Could anything be said regarding variations of $x^*$ depending on for instance variations in $Q$ and $b$ with respect to a matrix norm?
One special case that could be interesting is if the equality constraint is replaced by $1^\top x = 1$, i.e., the QP is solved on the simplex.

One special case analysis I found is for the linear least squares problem, see [On the Perturbation of Pseudo-Inverses, Projections and Linear Least Squares Problems, SIAM Review Vol. 19, No. 4 (Oct., 1977), pp. 634-662].
However, this does not generalize to the quadratic program in a straightforward manner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sensitivity analysis of optimization problems is called [parametric programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_programming) or sometimes "post-optimal analysis".

The short version is that you describe the variability of your optimization problem as a function of certain parameters, typically denotes as $\theta$. Then, you calculate the optimization problem *as a function* of $\theta$, i.e. $x^*(\theta)$. For QPs, the best way to do this is by solving the parametric version of the KKT conditions.

The solution of a parametric optimization problem is a series of so-called "critial regions", i.e. areas where an certain active set continues to be optimal despite a variation of the parameters. For each critical region you can calculate the analytical expression $x^*(\theta)$ (also for the Lagrangian multipliers).

There are some references around this topic that may interest you:

- Fiacco (1975): Basic Sensitivity Theory. This consolidates a lot of the theory, especially for the 1D case.
- Oberdieck et al. (2016) [On multi-parametric programming and its applications in process systems engineering](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0263876216303276). I wrote this review paper as a way for people who are new to the topic to learn what it is about.
- Pistikopoulos, Diangelakis, Oberdieck (2020) [Multi-parametric Optimization and Control](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Multi+parametric+Optimization+and+Control-p-9781119265184). We wrote this book as a continuation of the Fiacco book, summarizing a lot of the theory and known use cases for parametric programming.

> Apologies for self-referencing, I genuinely think these are good references though.